# Another phrase for 'the same as'

Tags: expressions

What is another phrase that could be used to replace 'the same as'?

To be used in a sentence such as: He was walking around the area, *the same as* everyone else.

Comment: Just Like everyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**just like**

He was walking around the area, just like everyone else.

**similar to**

He was walking around the area, similar to everyone else.

Comment: He was walking! Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V can be a nuisance :P

Comment: oops, my bad! thank you for pointing that..in my haste, i missed that out.

Answer (score 0):

'[***Exactly***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exactly) like' may work. '***[Identical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identical)***' looks less appropriate for the sample sentence.

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exactly

> Used to emphasize the accuracy of a figure or description:
>   *they met in 1989 and got married exactly two years later*

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identical

> Similar in every detail; exactly alike:
>   *four girls in identical green outfits*

Comment: but *walking exactly like everyone else* doesn't actually hold up, don't you think? two persons may not walk in an exact identical manner.

Comment: You have a point. I'm trying to stay as close to 'the same as' as I can, @Mama D.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

*He was walking around the area **the way** everyone else was.*

> the way:  like, as *we have cats the way other people have mice* —
>   James Thurber

**[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way)**